# Esper publisher and subscriber at different hosts

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

Is there any sample code that can have one host publishing events and the other host receiving the event (listener or subscriber) through the Esper framework. I notice Esper provides different adaptors (socket, JMS and HTTP) but cannot find corresponding sample code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EsperIO [1] would be what you are looking for
[1] http://esper.codehaus.org/esperio-4.9.0/doc/reference/en-US/html_single/index.html